# Using Alertify.js locally after downloading the library and source

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to include alertify.js on my webpage as a alert pop-up however I'm not sure why it is not being shown. I have downloaded the library and source for alertify though I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. Any suggestion would be great help. Thanks in advance!

```
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="C:/Users/Documents/alertifyjs/css/alertify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/Documents/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css" 
id="toggleCSS" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>
    .alertify-log-custom {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dialogs</h2>
<a href="#" id="alert">Alert Dialog</a><br>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="C:/Users/Documents/AlertifyJS-master/AlertifyJS- 
master/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function reset () {
        $("#toggleCSS").attr("href", "alertify.default.css");
        alertify.set({
            labels : {
                ok     : "OK",
                cancel : "Cancel"
            },
            delay : 5000,
            buttonReverse : false,
            buttonFocus   : "ok"
        });
    }

    $("#alert").on( 'click', function () {
        reset();
        alertify.alert("This is an alert dialog");
        return false;
    });
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the error shown on the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined
at b (alertify.min.js:2)
at Object.setting (alertify.min.js:2)
at Object.set (alertify.min.js:2)
at reset (alertify.html:44)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (alertify.html:56)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.js:3074)
at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.9.1.js:2750)
alertify.default.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: @BramVanroy I have updated the post to add the error shown on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead change this

```
alertify.set({
```

for this

```
alertify.confirm().set({
```

It happened to me and it depends on the alertify version

Answer (score 1):

by the path to your script, i guess you use windows with some kind of WAMP stack.
so if that's the case, you need to put your script in the same location with the rest of your files, ex: web or public_hml.
Also you should look for errors in the console. if the script can't be accesed, you should see a 404 in console.

Edit: you should load the style from the begining and add the needed class to your element via javascript.

Comment: It's a static file, so WAMP or similar is not necessary.

Comment: @Leonida I'll try to put the script on the same location